# Regular Expression with getting the value within the String

Tags: php, regex

I want to do a string replace within HTML content.

```
<!-- REPLACE_STRING_5 -->
```

In order to do that, i need to get the number of out the string (ID) I just want to check am I doing it correctly and efficiently?

```
<?php
$subject = "<!-- REPLACE_STRING_21 -->";
$pattern = '/^<!-- REPLACE_STRING_[0-9\.\-]+ -->/';

if(preg_match($pattern, $subject))
{
    $pos = strpos($subject, '-->');
    //20 is the number where the number postion start
    $pos = $pos - 20;
    echo substr($subject, 20, $pos);
}
else
{
    echo 'not match';
}
```

Comment: What do you want REPLACE_STRING_21 to look like when you're done?

Comment: I would need to get the '21' (21 is ID) out and look up the database and then get the content and replace this '<!-- REPLACE_STRING_21 -->'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to actually *replace* the number in `REPLACE_STRING_21` you could use lookarounds to do this:

```
(?<=<!-- REPLACE_STRING_)[-0-9.]+(?= -->)
```

[image]

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/tK5cI1

Since you want to capture the number out, you could use parentheses `()` to deploy capture groups, like so:

```
<!-- REPLACE_STRING_([-0-9.]+) -->
```

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/tV4tI3

You then need to retrieve the capture group 1 like so:

```
$subject = "<!-- REPLACE_STRING_21 -->";    
preg_match("/<!-- REPLACE_STRING_([-0-9.]+) -->/", $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
if (isset($matches[1]))
    echo $matches[1];
```

`$matches` will contain an array of matches, which in this case, `$matches[1]` is the one you're looking for.

Comment: This look around is new to me Thanks. It works. Up vote.

Comment: Thanks heaps r3mus for your help, your solution is much better approach then mine. much appreicated

Comment: You're welcome! Still working on the example for history's sake ;)